# SQL - How to select from mulitple possible columns names?

Tags: sql, select, db2, case

I need to get data from several tables, but the last piece of data I need can come from one of three tables, and each table uses a unique column name. I've tried setting up a CASE statement in the select, but I've obviously made a syntax error. Am I on the right track? Is there a better way? This is a DB2 database. I have limited access and do not think dyanmic SQL or creating a table is an option.

```
SELECT M1.MESSAGE_ID, M1.MESSAGE_NAME, M1.CREATED_DATETIME, M1.MESSAGE_SIZE, M2.PATH,
 case when select EXTRACTABLE_COUNT from MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT where exists (select M1.MESSAGE_ID from MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT)
    then select EXTRACTABLE_COUNT from MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT
 when select EXTRACTABLE_UNTIL from MBX_TIL_COUNT where exists (select M1.MESSAGE_ID from MBX_TIL_COUNT)
    then select EXTRACTABLE_UNTIL from MBX_TIL_COUNT
 when select EXTRACTABLE from MBX_EXTRACTABLE where exists (select M1.MESSAGE_ID from MBX_EXTRACTABLE)
    then select EXTRACTABLE from MBX_EXTRACTABLE
 end as EXTRACT_VALUE
FROM MBX_MESSAGE M1
 left JOIN MBX_MAILBOX M2
    ON M1.MAILBOX_ID = M2.MAILBOX_ID
 left JOIN MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT M3
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M3.MESSAGE_ID     
 left JOIN MBX_EXTRACT_TIL M4
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M4.MESSAGE_ID
 left JOIN MBX_EXTRACTABLE M5
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M4.MESSAGE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much off the top of my head:

```
SELECT 
  M1.MESSAGE_ID, 
  M1.MESSAGE_NAME, 
  M1.CREATED_DATETIME, 
  M1.MESSAGE_SIZE, 
  EV.EXTRACT_VALUE,
  M2.PATH
FROM MBX_MESSAGE MI
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    MESSAGE_ID, 
    EXTRACTABLE_COUNT AS EXTRACT_VALUE
  FROM MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    MESSAGE_ID,
    EXTRACTABLE_UNTIL AS EXTRACT_VALUE
  FROM MBX_TIL_COUNT

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    MESSAGE_ID,
    EXTRACTABLE AS EXTRACT_VALUE
  FROM MBX_EXTRACTABLE

) AS EV ON MI.MESSAGE_ID = EV.MESSAGE_ID
LEFT JOIN MBX_MAILBOX M2
  ON M1.MAILBOX_ID = M2.MAILBOX_ID
```

I am sure this could be improved a bit, but using a sub-query with `UNION ALL` like this should pull everything into one column named `EXTRACT_VALUE`

Comment: This worked! I had to make a few modifications, since I forgot to mention that EXTRACTABLE_UNTIL is a date value. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT MESSAGE_ID,     
                EXTRACTABLE_COUNT EXTRACT_VALUE
           FROM MBX_EXTRACT_COUNT) M3
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M3.MESSAGE_ID     
LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT MESSAGE_ID,     
                EXTRACTABLE_UNTIL EXTRACT_VALUE
           FROM MBX_EXTRACT_TIL) M4
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M4.MESSAGE_ID
LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT MESSAGE_ID,     
                EXTRACTABLE EXTRACT_VALUE
           FROM MBX_EXTRACTABLE) M5
    ON M1.MESSAGE_ID = M5.MESSAGE_ID
```

In this way all the columns should have the same name, then `COALESCE` should be enough.

Anyway your last `LEFT JOIN` had wrong condition, it should be M5 instead of M4